# replace Value in a dataframe depending on another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes :

```
   >>> tab1
        Value       Sp_name    
    0   None        ROOT  
    1   0.066       Genus_1_sp1
    2   0.1044      Genus_2_sp1
    3   0.0708      EDGE  
    4   0.0586      Genus_3_sp1
    5   0.0083      Genus_4_sp1
```

and the idea is to parse another data frame such as :

```
>>> tab2
Old_name             New_name
Genus_1_sp1_A     Genus_1_sp1
Genus_2_sp1_A     Genus_2_sp1
Genus_3_sp1_A     Genus_3_sp1
Genus_4_sp1_A     Genus_4_sp1
```

and in replace `Sp_name` in the tab1 that match the `New_name` in `tab2`, and then replace the `Sp_name` by the corresponding `Old_name`
In the exemple I should get :

```
>>> tab1
    Value       Sp_name    
0   None        ROOT  
1   0.066       Genus_1_sp1_A
2   0.1044      Genus_2_sp1_A
3   0.0708      EDGE  
4   0.0586      Genus_3_sp1_A
5   0.0083      Genus_4_sp1_A
```

I tried so far:

```
for i in tab1['Sp_name']:
    found= tab2[tab2['New_name'].str.contains(i)]
    if len(found) > 0:
        tab1.at[i,'Sp_name'] = str(row['Old_name'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a name dictionary from `tab2` then use `.replace` to replace it back to `tab1`

```
name_dict = dict(zip(tab2.New_name, tab2.Old_name))
tab1['Sp_name'] = tab1['Sp_name'].replace(name_dict)

tab1

    Value        Sp_name
0    None           ROOT
1   0.066  Genus_1_sp1_A
2  0.1044  Genus_2_sp1_A
3  0.0708           EDGE
4  0.0586  Genus_3_sp1_A
5  0.0083  Genus_4_sp1_A
```

Answer (score 1):

using [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df['Sp_name'] = pd.merge(df1,df2.rename(columns={'New_name':'Sp_name'}),how='left' ,on='Sp_name').apply(lambda x: x['Old_name'] if x['Old_name'] == np.nan else x['Sp_name'], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    Value      Sp_name
0    None         ROOT
1   0.066  Genus_1_sp1
2  0.1044  Genus_2_sp1
3  0.0708         EDGE
4  0.0586  Genus_3_sp1
5  0.0083  Genus_4_sp1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [DataFrame.update](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update). It is designed for such requirement. Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.

Here is my sample code for your reference:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

tab1="""
Value,Sp_name
None,ROOT
0.066,Genus_1_sp1
0.1044,Genus_2_sp1
0.0708,EDGE
0.0586,Genus_3_sp1
0.0083,Genus_4_sp1
"""
tab2="""
Old_name,New_name
Genus_1_sp1_A,Genus_1_sp1
Genus_2_sp1_A,Genus_2_sp1
Genus_3_sp1_A,Genus_3_sp1
Genus_4_sp1_A,Genus_4_sp1A
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(tab1)).set_index("Sp_name",drop=False)

df2=  pd.read_csv(StringIO(tab2)).rename(columns={"Old_name":"Sp_name"}).set_index("New_name")
df1.index.name ='New_name'

new_df = df1.copy()
new_df.update(df2)

print("\nthis is table 1 ")
pprint(df1,)

print("\nthis is table 2 ")

pprint(df2,)

print("\nthis is updated table")

pprint(new_df.reset_index(drop=True),)
```

And here is the output.

```
this is table 1 
              Value      Sp_name
New_name                        
ROOT           None         ROOT
Genus_1_sp1   0.066  Genus_1_sp1
Genus_2_sp1  0.1044  Genus_2_sp1
EDGE         0.0708         EDGE
Genus_3_sp1  0.0586  Genus_3_sp1
Genus_4_sp1  0.0083  Genus_4_sp1

this is table 2 
                    Sp_name
New_name                   
Genus_1_sp1   Genus_1_sp1_A
Genus_2_sp1   Genus_2_sp1_A
Genus_3_sp1   Genus_3_sp1_A
Genus_4_sp1A  Genus_4_sp1_A

this is updated table
    Value        Sp_name
0    None           ROOT
1   0.066  Genus_1_sp1_A
2  0.1044  Genus_2_sp1_A
3  0.0708           EDGE
4  0.0586  Genus_3_sp1_A
5  0.0083    Genus_4_sp1
```

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations !

Comment: Welcom. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for mapping. It is the most vectorised too (IMO):

```
tab1.Sp_name=tab1.Sp_name.map(tab2.set_index('New_name')['Old_name']).fillna(tab1.Sp_name)
print(tab1)
```

---

```
    Value        Sp_name
0    None           ROOT
1   0.066  Genus_1_sp1_A
2  0.1044  Genus_2_sp1_A
3  0.0708           EDGE
4  0.0586  Genus_3_sp1_A
5  0.0083  Genus_4_sp1_A
```